# Как при создании вызова, вызывать подсказку всех его свойств?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть такая схема, но порой забываю что там за свойства, и не хочу идти к схемам и альтабаться. Увидел такое у одного преподавателя, он просто остановил курсор, нажал горячие клавишы и у него всплала подсказка. Здесь используется ts + prisma + vscode

Answer (score 1):

Узнал составив вопрос в гугле. Вот такие ключевые слова Editing JSON with Visual Studio Code.

Ответ <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Пакет называется All Autocomplete (marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Atishay-Jain.All-Autocomplete)